# Disabling Cache for CloudFront

Tags: amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I am using my own domain to serve HTTPS s3 bucket via CloudFront. I don't want it to cache since its for QA environment.

I'm wondering how could i achieve this. Is it by Using Origin Cache Headers  or Customize with 0 Time To Live?

Comment: If you are seeing cached content and want to clear the cache, you can do so by navigating to your CloudFront distribution > Invalidations > Create Invalidation and then entering "*" (everything) for the file path of objects that you wish to be invalidated.

Comment: @blairnangle That solution costs around $0.005 pr. object. So it's really the nuclear option. There are several free ways to do it: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-cloudfront-from-caching-files/

Comment: Under the [Behavior] section, choose the cache policy: [Managed-CachingDisabled]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please use **customize option (Behavior -> Cache Behavior Settings)** in AWS management console (CloudFront) and input the value for Minimum TTL, Default TTL, and Maximum TTL accordingly.

> Minimum TTL
>
> Specify the minimum amount of time, in seconds, that you want objects
>   to stay in CloudFront caches before CloudFront forwards another
>   request to your origin to determine whether the object has been
>   updated. The default value for Minimum TTL is 0 seconds.
>
> Maximum TTL
>
> Specify the maximum amount of time, in seconds, that you want objects
>   to stay in CloudFront caches before CloudFront queries your origin to
>   see whether the object has been updated. The value that you specify
>   for Maximum TTL applies only when your origin adds HTTP headers such
>   as Cache-Control max-age, Cache-Control s-maxage, or Expires to
>   objects.
>
> Default TTL
>
> Specify the default amount of time, in seconds, that you want objects
>   to stay in CloudFront caches before CloudFront forwards another
>   request to your origin to determine whether the object has been
>   updated. The value that you specify for Default TTL applies only when
>   your origin does not add HTTP headers such as Cache-Control max-age,
>   Cache-Control s-maxage, or Expires to objects.

Answer (score 16):

Now, you can simply set the cachingDisabled policy on the cloudfront behavior.

On the AWS cloudfront console:

- go to your distribution -> behaviours tab
- edit the behaviour
- Under **Cache key and origin requests** header -> Select the
  cachingDisabled policy

Comment: it might answer the question, but i suggest you  to add a source to proof it :-)

Comment: here's a source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/prevent-cloudfront-from-caching-files/

thanks for the answer!